# "expo publish" not working for app built with EAS + expo-dev-client

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm using the new [expo-dev-client](https://docs.expo.dev/development/introduction/) and [EAS](https://docs.expo.dev/development/eas-build/) workflow to attempt development with expo, while also including native dependencies (react-native-firebase in my case).

I've managed to build and install a preview of my app with EAS:

```
eas build --platform ios --profile staging
```

Where my "staging" profile is setup in `eas.json` like so:

```
{
   "cli": {
      "version": ">= 0.35.0"
   },
   "build": {
      "production": {
         "releaseChannel": "prod-v0",
         "node": "14.17.4",
         "ios": {
            "cocoapods": "1.11.2",
            "autoIncrement": "buildNumber"
         }
      },
      "staging": {
         "extends": "production",
         "releaseChannel": "staging",
         "distribution": "internal"
      },
      ...
   },
   ...
}
```

Note the `releaseChannel` is set to "staging" too.

So far so good. The app is building and I can install it on my device and confirm the releaseChannel using the `expo-updates` module with `Updates.releaseChannel`

Now I'd like to publish a pure javascript change, so I run...

```
expo publish --release-channel staging
```

But this gives the following warning (which I assume is why I don't see the update on my device):

```
ios: Expo.plist key: "EXUpdatesReleaseChannel": The value passed to the 
--release-channel flag is to "staging", but it is set to "default".
```

So what/where is "Expo.plist", why isn't it in-sync, and how can I update it?

**Update:**

So I deleted the iOS folder from a previous `expo run:ios` build. The warning is now gone when running `expo publish --release-channel staging`. But still nothing seems to happen on my app - it still doesn't update.

Comment: Any update on this would be appreciated.  I have same issue.  Using eas build and expo publish... same release channels... app never updates?

Comment: I haven't pushed it any further yet. My next step was going to be creating a small repo to to replicate the issue then, assuming I replicate it, post a bug report. Just haven't got there yet.

Comment: Still no update? I'm having this exact same issue right now.

Comment: @pbrune seems this was fixed in the past few days by expo.  It now works again. Seems EAS was missing the release channel.

Comment: @BenWalton thanks for the heads up. Yeah I noticed it the other day when I used expo publish it actually worked.